# I can't replace my JLabel which is in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

So I want to "move" my `JLabel` which is included to a panel. When I change the first number at `setBounds` for my label (`bcopy`) its location doesn't change. What did I do wrong?

```
bcopy = new JLabel("CST made by ColdStormy");
    bcopy.setBounds(50, 0, 100, 25);
    add(bcopy);

bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        bottom.setBounds(0, 450, 750, 50);
        bottom.add(bcopy);
        add(bottom);
```

If it's important here's the code for the frame in the main-class:

```
Frame frame = new Frame();

    frame.setSize(750, 500);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setTitle("ChampionSelectTool - Help yourself selecting champions!");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Use a `LayoutManager`, `JFrame` instead of `Frame`, `Frame` does not have a `setDefaultCloseOperation` method

Comment: Plus you add `bcopy` to two different containers. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: *"..want to "move" my `JLabel`.."* Why?

Answer (score 0):

When you dynamically add/remove components the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint(); // sometimes needed
```